# Google analytics - do not track campaigns. (tagged links from banners leading to a site)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

i have GA connected site.
I have banners, with outgoing tagged link - 
http://www.czgezinnen.nl/?utm_source=clickdistrict-cpm&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=CZgezinnen

and i don't see campaign statistics in Traffic Sources - Campaigns.
should I do smth else to swich on campaign tracking on my GA account fro current site?

may be it's not working because i have a flash site, with GA for flash?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're tracking it just fine. For example, here is the value for the __utmz cookie for when I click through to your site:

```
116033492.1290446486.1.1.utmcsr=clickdistrict-cpm|utmccn=CZgezinnen|utmcmd=banner
```

That indicates that the campaign information is tracking just fine.

But, sometimes you need to wait a little longer for campaign data to process.

The summary of your __utm.gif hit indicates there's nothing wrong with the tracking:

```
Account ID               : UA-19793814-1
Host Name                : www.czgezinnen.nl
Page                     : /?utm_source=clickdistrict-cpm&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=CZgezinnen
Referring URL            : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244621/google-analytics-do-not-track-campaigns-tagged-links-from-banners-leading-to
Hit ID                   : 419250843
Visitor ID               : 890842162
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Mon Nov 22 2010 12:21:26 GMT-0500 (EST)
Session Time - Last      : Mon Nov 22 2010 12:21:26 GMT-0500 (EST)
Session Time - Current   : Mon Nov 22 2010 12:21:26 GMT-0500 (EST)
Campaign Time            : Mon Nov 22 2010 12:21:26 GMT-0500 (EST)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : clickdistrict-cpm
Campaign Medium          : banner;
Campaign Name            : CZgezinnen
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 10.1 r103
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 1280x800
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 4.8.6d
Async Snippet Used       : false
Cachebuster              : 816335729
```